# React : Returning SVG contents as variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, gatsby

I am currently doing this:

```
class Checked extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <svg width="24" fill="#00ea00" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                <path d="M9 16.17L4.83 12l-1.42 1.41L9 19 21 7l-1.41-1.41z"/>
            </svg>
        );
    }
}
```

But I would like to be doing something like this:

```
import imgTable from '../img/catering_table.svg'

class Checked extends React.Component {
  render() {
      return imgTable;
  }
}
```

Why does this not work? Am I returning the variable here and not the actual contents? I would have thought the two are equivalent.

PS: Webpack is set up correctly, I am using imports somewhere else in that file, so it's not that. (I am using GatsbyJS here by the way)

Answer (score 6):

**Option 1**: Wrap with a stateless component:

```
const ImgTable = () => (
  <svg width="24" fill="#00ea00" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
      <path d="M9 16.17L4.83 12l-1.42 1.41L9 19 21 7l-1.41-1.41z"/>
  </svg>
);

export default ImgTable;
```

Now you can import it as a component:

```
import ImgTable from '../img/ImgTable'

class Checked extends React.Component {
  render() {
      return <ImgTable />;
  }
}
```

**Option 2**: Use [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) (notice the name). However, you'll need to convert the SVG to string on import using something like [babel-plugin-transform-svg-import-to-string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-svg-import-to-string):

```
import imgTable from '../img/catering_table.svg' // this will return a string

class Checked extends React.Component {
  render() {
      return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: imgTable }} />;
  }
}
```

Comment: Finally I realise it don't help the OP. he want to insert his svp from a .svg file. 
It can maybe done with a wrapper and the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML={svg_content}`

Comment: `import imgTable from '../img/catering_table.svg'` imports it as a relative URL for me.

Answer (score 3):

`babel-plugin-inline-react-svg` is a plugin that allows you do exactly what you hinted at in your question. It simply creates a react component for every node in the svg file. Then it wraps the the entire component tree with a root element that you can easily name.

Import you svg like this `import SampleSVG from './sample.svg';`. And render it in your application like this `<SampleSVG />`. It's safe and simple.

Answer (score -2):

You can pass an SVG to a variable in React as follows:

```js
  const checkIcon = {
    icon: <svg data-name="Group 1642" width="25.771" height="25.771" className="info--text-icon" viewBox="0 0 25.771 25.771">
      <path data-name="Path 99" d="M11.979 17.51h-.021a.97.97 0 01-.694-.313l-4.889-5.309a.971.971 0 011.429-1.316l4.2 4.566L23.661 3.521a.971.971 0 111.371 1.375L12.665 17.231a.972.972 0 01-.686.279z" fill="#44bbc7" ></path><path data-name="Path 100" d="M12.885 25.771a12.885 12.885 0 010-25.771.971.971 0 010 1.943 10.943 10.943 0 1010.943 10.942.971.971 0 011.943 0 12.9 12.9 0 01-12.886 12.886z" fill="#44bbc7" ></path>
    </svg>
  };
```

And to call the variable:

```js
const Informations = () => {
  return (
      <>
       {check.icon} This is SVG with React
      </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't the variable usage be `{checkIcon.icon}` though?